# How to write PUT request in curl and access the parameters in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

Please have a look at my implementation:

https://github.com/NITIN-ME/Node.js/blob/master/basic_restful.js

Comment: just use `PUT` in the request. send parameters like post

Comment: But how to access the parameters using node?

Comment: like you already accessed for `POST`

Comment: My question is, what if there are multiple named parameters?

Comment: Per the rules of this site, code needed to understand your question must be pasted into your question directly and formatted appropriately, NOT only available via an external link.

Comment: Data from a PUT or POST request will be in the body of the request and must be read by you from the request stream and then decoded according to the encoding listed in the request.

Comment: FYI, if you use the Express framework for simple web servers, then the body-parser middleware can be used to automatically read and parse the body from a PUT or POST for you and just make it available in `req.body` on each request.